# Jenkins: Include one groovy pipeline script into another

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

Specifically for Jenkins, I wish to have a file with common functions. I have tried a number of options such as load and also as a new class but none have worked for me so far.

Things tried:

```
newScript = new newScript ()  // to load a file called
newScript.groovy  // also didn't work
helpers = load "newScript.groovy"// also didn't work
```

def helpers = load "newScript.groovy"

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this : (For scripted pipeline)

1.First checkout that repository which has that common functions file and after that add the below line.

```
u4pipe = load("path to the groovy while which has common functions")
```